# Проблемы с TabWidget

Tags: android

Есть макет с вкладками. Элемент TabWidget располагается внизу экрана (на дне :)). Содержимое каждой вкладки - активити. Вот макет одной из активити упрощённо выглядит следующим образом:

```
<RelativeLayout... >
  <EditText.../>
  <ListView... >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот, когда я перехожу в эту вкладку, фокус падает на EditText, открывается клавиатура и !!! TabWidget поднимается вверх!!! он отображается над клавиатурой, при закрытии клавиатуры TabWidget  встаёт на своё место. Если ListView убрать, то таких проблем нет.

Comment: возможно проблема в <RelativeLayout... >, замени на LinearLayout

Comment: не помогло)

Comment: покажи весь активити с TabWidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте выставить для соответствующего элемента *activity* в *AndroidManifest.xml* значение атрибута *android:windowSoftInputMode*. Если я правильно понял задачу, вам подойдут значения *adjustPan* или *adjustResize*.

Comment: спаибо, подошло. для активити с табами вставила строку android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan".